# MuleStudio - Error failed failed to load the JNI shared library

Tags: jvm, java, mule, mule-studio

I have Windows 7 installation with 32 bit JDK.

When I try to run MuleStudio.exe I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the 32 bit edition, which is rather hard to find on the first page.

**Deprecation notice:** The link is valid just for Mule Studio and not for the new Anypoint Studio. Basically think link is just for historical purposes here and there is a 99% chance this is the wrong link for you.

[**Check the All Mule Studio Downloads page.**](http://www.mulesoft.org/all-mule-studio-downloads) and select the 32 bit version.

Comment: I've the same problem on 64 bit windows machine. The studio version is : MuleStudio-for-win-64bit-3.5.0-201312091746

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

- open your AnypointStudio.ini with notepad
- add or edit the vm

  -vm

  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin // edit this with the path of your installed jdk

Comment: this path is not his path, his path may different

Comment: it's just example. :)